# PHPExcel reset drawing shapes

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm having the following problem. I have the file with a single arrow shape (you can download it here http://www.filedropper.com/excel_2). So I just open this file and save it to output. As a result I have the empty file. Here is my code:

```
$obj = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('excel.xlsx');
$reportWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($obj);
$reportWriter->setIncludeCharts(true);

header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=excel.xlsx');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$reportWriter->save('php://output');
```

If I have values and borders in the file, they are not removed after I resave the file. Only shapes are removed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if PHPExcel can load also shapes.
In my opinion the problem is already on the first row of your code.

```
$obj = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('excel.xlsx');
```

Already in object `$obj` isn't information about shapes. I don't know, how to parametrize load method for loading also shapes. I think, this feature is not implemented yet.

Comment: Yeah, suppose it's not possible. There is the same issue in the Github project https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/928